# if contents of container element are taller than container element, add class to container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Due to a not great design that's out of my hands, there are many elements on this particular site that have fixed heights. Because of that, the content inside of these elements is getting cut off when it's taller than the fixed height. So basically I want to add a class of 'expandable' to all the fixed height container elements on the page *if* the content inside is getting cut off because it's taller than the container. Just looking to see if I'm doing this correctly. Thanks for the help.

```
feature = $('.feature-block');

feature.each(function() {
  containerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  containerChildren = $(this).children();

  containerChildren.each(function() {
    childrenHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

    if(childrenHeight > containerHeight) {
        $(this).closest(feature).addClass('expandable');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: why do you need JS? even some small css fix covered the main container height. For example `display:table` on the main container cover it, and remove the fixed height if given.

Comment: you can override the CSS and make height auto

Comment: Why dont you just add a CSS rule that resets the height of those elements? a simple `.feature-block{height:auto!important}` would do the trick, and if for some reason you cant edit the CSS, you could do `$('.feature-block').css('height','auto')`. If their current height is the needed minimum, adding `min-height` is possible.

Comment: because all of the container elements `.feature-block` have an arrow that you can click (again, not my idea) whether or not the inner content > container. the click only functions (sets height to auto) if the container has the class 'expandable'. not ideal, but the customer gets what they want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum children heights:

```
feature.each(function() {
  var containerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(),
      containerChildren = $(this).children(),
      childrenHeight = 0;

  containerChildren.each(function() {
    childrenHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
  });

  if(childrenHeight > containerHeight) {
     $(this).closest(feature).addClass('expandable');
  }
});
```